# Is an open subset of an open set of a topological space open?

Tags: general-topology

If $X$ is an topological space and $ U \subseteq V \subseteq X$ with $V$ open in $X$ and $U$ open in $V$, is it true that $U$ is open in $X$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. $U$ open in $V$ means that $U=V\cap W$ for some $W$ open in $X$. So $U$ is an intersection of two open sets in $X$.

Comment: Thank you (five more characters)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: $U $ is open in  $V $ iff $U=V\cap S $ for some  $S $ open in $X $.

Comment: Is this just the definition of U being open in V?

Comment: Yes. This is how a subspace topology is defined.