# Is $A\setminus \{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ an open set if $A$ is open?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, solution-verification, metric-spaces

> let $A$ be an open set of the metric space $(X,d)$. Now I wanted to prove that for any $x_1,\dots,x_n\in X$ also the set $$A\setminus \{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$$ is open.

---

My idea was the following. Let $a\in A\setminus \{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$. Since $A$ is open there exists $r>0$ such that $B(a,r)\subset A$. Now let me define $$r' = \min \left \{ r, \min_{k=1, \dots,n} d(a,x_k)\right\}$$ then clearly $r'\leq r$ and hence $B(a,r')\subset U$. But, by construction, $x_k\notin B(a,r')$ for all $k$, hence $B(a,r') \subset A \setminus \{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$.

Does this work or did I miss something? If it is wrong could you maybe show me why?

Comment: Your proof works fine.

Comment: @geetha290krm perfect thanks a lot!

Comment: An other way : $A\setminus \{x_1,...,x_n\}=A\cap(\{x_1,...,x_n\}^c)$ which is open because finite intersection of open sets...

Comment: @Surb I see thanks!

Comment: Your proof is OK. See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4529020/proof-that-every-finite-subset-of-a-metric-space-is-closed/ and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3027254/is-an-open-subset-of-an-open-set-of-a-topological-space-open

Comment: It is much easier to prove that any finite set in a metric space is closed. And hence an open set minus a closed set will always stay open(Though this is a very standard result , you might not be familiar with it. Try and prove this : if $U$ is open(resp closed) and $V$ is closed(resp open), then $U\setminus V$ is open(resp closed)) . You can use the properties of subspace toplogy(metric) or can prove it directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is absolutely correct. The intuition is that if $a\in A\setminus\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$, then $a$ is an interior point of $A$, i.e. you can draw an open ball centred around $a$ which is wholly contained in $A$. Now it might be that this open ball contains one of the points $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n$. However, since the set $S=\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ is finite, there must be an $x_i$ which is closest to $a$, and so you simply shrink the open ball so that $x_i$ is no longer included in it, and hence none of the members of $S$ are included in it.

The key point in this proof is that there is an $x_i$ which is closest to $A$. If $S$ were infinite instead, then this is no longer guaranteed: e.g. $\{(x,y):x^2+y^2<1\}$ is open in $\mathbb R^2$ under the standard distance metric, but $\{(x,y):x^2+y^2<1\}\setminus\{(x,y):x^2+y^2<1/2\}$ is not.

Comment: Is there a mistake in my answer?

Comment: I don't think there is.

Comment: I do not see any mistake, except (maybe) that the question was only "Does this (proof) work or did I miss something? If it is wrong could you maybe show me why?".

Comment: Can I say that if $S=(x_n)_{n\geq 1}\subset X$ is a sequence, then $A\setminus S$ is not open?

Comment: Because I considered the example where $(X,d)=(\Bbb{R},d)$ and $A=(-1,1)$ then I take $x_n=\frac{1}{n}$. Then clearly for $a=0$ there is no radius such that $B(0,r)$ lies in $A\setminus S$.


is this correct?

Comment: @Haveaniceday: If $A$ is an open set, and $S$ is countably infinite (i.e. its members can be arranged in a sequence $(x_n)$), then $A\setminus S$ might still be open.

Comment: First of all, we can note that if $S\cap A = \varnothing$, then $A\setminus S = A$. Second, even if we require that $S$ is a subset of $A$, it still might be that $A\setminus S$ is open. For instance, the set $(0,1)$ is open in $\mathbb R$, and it remains open even if you remove points taking the form $x_n=1/(n+1)$ [exercise]. However, as your example shows, removing a countably infinite set of points *could* give you a set which is not open. Does that help? Feel free to ask more questions if you are still unsure about something.

Comment: @Joe thanks a lot. So this means my example is correct and it shows that there is the possibility that $A\setminus S$ is not open anymore, but it still could be open right?

Comment: @Joe Sorry for the second question, but if I take $(-1,1)$ in your first example then it would not be open right?

Comment: @Haveaniceday: Yep, both of your points are correct. By the way, the "obvious" fact that you can find numbers of the form $1/n$ which are arbitrarily close to $0$ is a result of the [Archimedean property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property) of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @Joe perfect thanks!

Comment: @Haveaniceday: No problem! I'm glad I could help. You might want to consider marking my answer as the accepted one.